# How can I convert det unix time values from txt file to date values using matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, unix, matplotlib

I basically want to convert the unix time values I have in the first row of my text file named 'EKTE9' to date. I think using the datetime library is the way to go, but I don't know how to implement that in my code. Some answers would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('EKTE9.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[3]))

plt.plot(x,y, label='Temperatur')
plt.xlabel('Tid')
plt.ylabel('Temperatur')
plt.title('Grafen viser temperatur under forsøket\n')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here are some values from the EKTE9.txt file:

```
1554058225,0.80,2.90,13.60,27.20
1554058525,0.30,0.80,9.60,26.70
```

The values goes on for about 200 lines

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question to include some lines from `EKTE9.txt` so we can understand what the format is.

Comment: That did the job, ty Martin Evans. Means a lot

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up and down buttons to select the answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That did the job. Thank you very much Martin Evans.
Fina code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('EKTE9.txt','r') as csvfile:
     plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

     for row in plots:
        x.append(matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row[0]))))
        y.append(float(row[3]))

hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d\n%H:%M')
plt.plot(x,y, label='Temperatur')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
plt.xlabel('Tid')
plt.ylabel('Temperatur')
plt.title('Grafen viser temperatur under forsøket\n')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first create a `datetime` object using [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromtimestamp#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp). This can then be converted to a matplotlib number using [`date2num()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num). Finally, you should use a [`DateFormatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) to help with displaying the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('EKTE9.txt', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in plots:
        x.append(matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row[0]))))
        y.append(float(row[3]))

hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d\n%H:%M')
plt.plot(x,y, label='Temperatur')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
plt.xlabel('Tid')
plt.ylabel('Temperatur')
plt.title('Grafen viser temperatur under forsøket\n')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This would then show your two values as follows:

[image: Matplotlib output]